# Not able to construct List Iterator from list.begin()

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I am solving this problem https://leetcode.com/problems/queue-reconstruction-by-height/

This is the code that I wrote

```
vector<vector<int>> reconstructQueue(vector<vector<int>>& people) {  
    list<vector<int>> dyn;
        
    sort(people.begin(), people.end(), [](vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
        if (a[0] > b[0]) return true;
        else if (a[0] == b[0] && a[1]<b[1]) return true;
        return false;
    });
            
    for (auto p: people) 
        cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << endl;
        
    for (int i = 0; i != people.size(); i++) {
        auto it = dyn.begin() + people[i][1];
        dyn.insert(it, people[i]);
    }
        
    vector<vector<int>> ans(dyn.begin(), dyn.end());
        
    return ans;    
}
```

the test case is

```
people = [[7,0],[4,4],[7,1],[5,0],[6,1],[5,2]]
```

I have not used lists that much. It gives error at

```
auto it = dyn.begin() + people[i][1];
```

```
Line 17: Char 35: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__cxx11::list<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>>>::iterator' (aka '_List_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>>') and '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int>, int>::value_type' (aka 'int'))
            auto it = dyn.begin() + people[i][1];
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_bvector.h:303:3: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__cxx11::list<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>>>::iterator' (aka '_List_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>>') to 'std::ptrdiff_t' (aka 'long') for 1st argument
  operator+(ptrdiff_t __n, const _Bit_iterator& __x)
  ^
```

I have dry run and at least in this particular test case, there is no out-of-bound possibility. Can anyone please suggest why this is happening.

Comment: The iterator does not support the '+' operator. It only supports `++` and `--`. Please look at `std::advance`.

Comment: Glad I could help. I added some more details and expanded it to a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::list.begin()` produces a BidirectionalIterator.

As per the documentation at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator, this type of iterator does not support the `+' operator.
The only permissable operators are:

- `++`: Move to next iterator location.
- `--`: Move to previous iterator location
- `*--`: Dereference the iterator (return the item) and then move to next.

To achieve what you want, you will need the `std::advance` function, which takes a reference to the iterator (so you cannot pass `list.begin()` directly) and the number of steps you wish to take.

It is roughly equivalent to the following loop (for a positive value):

```
ListType::iterator it = list.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    ++it;
```

So, to solve your immediate problem, your code needs to be:

```
for(int i=0; i!=people.size(); i++) {        
    auto it = dyn.begin();
    std::advance(it, people[i][1]);
    dyn.insert(it, people[i]);
}
```

Alternatively, you may want to switch to an `std::vector`, which produces a `RandomAccessIterator` which can be used a lot like you would use an array pointer. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)

Comment: Some iterators do support `+`. It's  unrelated to containers using arrays under the hood, it only depends on the iterator category.

Comment: Many iterators do support +, - arithmetics. It just varies from container to container.

Comment: You are of course correct, @HolyBlackCat. I amended my answer to reflect that.